# unable to access linq properties with c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert the vb code (below) to c#.  The c# code a the bottom doesn't like the this.UserLogin or this.CompanyID, this.CompanyType or this.CreatedDateTime.  It gives the error CT_CompanyLogin does not contain a definition for UserLogin and no extension method UserLogin accepting a first argument of type CT_CompanyLogin could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help??

VB

```
Partial Class CT_CompanyLogin

    Public Function GetCompanyAssoicatedByUserID() As Boolean
        Dim db As DataClassesDataContext = New DataClassesDataContext()

        Try

        Dim mycompany = (From c In db.CT_CompanyLogIns _
                        Where c.UserLogIn = Me.UserLogIn _
                        Select c).Single

            Me.CompanyID = mycompany.CompanyID
            Me.CompanyType = mycompany.CompanyType
            Me.CreatedDateTime = mycompany.CreatedDateTime
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False

        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

C#

```
partial class CT_CompanyLogin
{
    public Boolean GetCompanyAssociatedByUserID()
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

        try
        {
            var mycompany = (from c in db.CT_CompanyLogIns
                         where c.UserLogIn == this.UserLogin
                         select c).Single();

            this.CompanyID = mycompany.CompanyID;
            this.CompanyType = mycompany.CompanyType;
            this.CreatedDateTime = mycompany.CreatedDateTime;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the wrong spelling, vb is not case sensitive where c# is, so in the partial classes one was CT_CompanyLogIn and the other was CT_CompanyLogin

Answer (score 3):

This is a *partial class*.  You need to make sure that the other portion of the class files (which contain the definition of `CompanyID`, `UserLogin`, etc) are ported first.

This will likely mean migrating your LINQ to SQL designer over to the C# project, and building it.  This should build the partial class definition with these properties.

Comment: The other portion of the partial class is in the dbml file, which contains the definition for the properties, is that all I need?  I already had that, but it doesn't work

Comment: @user1202606 You need to make sure that it's building properly in the same project - it obviously isn't.

Comment: @user1202606 Check your namespaces, as well - if you're dbml is building into a different namespace, that would do it...

Comment: I have another partial class called CT_Company and that one is working just fine with the linq partial class.  Any clue why one would work and the other wouldn't?  They are referencing the same libraries.

Comment: @user1202606 The partial class must be **in the same project**.  They are turned into a single class at compile time.

Comment: They are in the same project.  The CT_Company.cs, CT_CompanyLogin.cs and DataClasses.dbml are all in the App_Code folder together, along with CT_basePage.

Comment: also, not using namespaces in the project.  It was already like that in vb, so I'm just doing the same thing in c#

Comment: it was the wrong spelling.  In the CT_CompanyLogIn in the dbml, I had a capital I, in the partial class CT_CompanyLogin, I has a lower case i.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's nothing to do with LINQ here - it's just that you haven't declared `CompanyID`, `CompanyType` or `CreatedTime` properties/fields in the class you're coding in. Just some VB code you haven't ported yet, perhaps? These are partial classes - perhaps you should look in the other VB files which make up the complete type?

Comment: I meant to add that in a comment .....but I put the code in the partial class above.